# Speed up python code for computing matrix cofactors

Tags: python, matrix, performance, numpy, linear-algebra

As part of a complex task, I need to compute [matrix cofactors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofactor_%28linear_algebra%29).  I did this in a straightforward way using this [nice code for computing matrix minors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858213/numpy-routine-for-computing-matrix-minors).  Here is my code:

```
def matrix_cofactor(matrix):
    C = np.zeros(matrix.shape)
    nrows, ncols = C.shape
    for row in xrange(nrows):
        for col in xrange(ncols):
            minor = matrix[np.array(range(row)+range(row+1,nrows))[:,np.newaxis],
                           np.array(range(col)+range(col+1,ncols))]
            C[row, col] = (-1)**(row+col) * np.linalg.det(minor)
    return C
```

It turns out that this matrix cofactor code is the bottleneck, and I would like to optimize the code snippet above.  Any ideas as to how to do this?

Comment: The general bottleneck-killer is to write the bottleneck in C. Is there some teChnician around here?

Comment: Care to elaborate why you need to compute 'cofactors' ? Would it be possible just avoid it and try to find a more straightforward solution to your problem? Even with following `borrible`s suggestion, you won't get anyway near such speed-up, what might be possible when interpreting the problem from 'proper angle' (if possible). Thanks

Comment: @eat, not possible to avoid them.  Too complicated to explain here...

Comment: @Jeff: Please note that based on `pv`s answer, there exists a real barrier, which you can't expect to overpass. So, only algorithmical 'innovations' are the means to really enable you to move substantially further (at least performance wise). Thanks

Comment: if you trying to compute determinants the best method would be chio rule of pivotal condensation.

Comment: The usual method for determinants in numerical linear algebra is to compute the LU decomposition and find the determinant from the triangular L and U. The computational complexity for det and LU is essentially the same, and as optimized libraries for LU exist, one probably is hard pressed to beat them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your matrix is invertible, the cofactor is related to the inverse:

```
def matrix_cofactor(matrix):
    return np.linalg.inv(matrix).T * np.linalg.det(matrix)
```

This gives large speedups (~ 1000x for 50x50 matrices). The main reason is fundamental: this is an `O(n^3)` algorithm, whereas the minor-det-based one is `O(n^5)`.

This probably means that also for non-invertible matrixes, there is some clever way to calculate the cofactor (i.e., not use the mathematical formula that you use above, but some other equivalent definition).

---

If you stick with the det-based approach, what you can do is the following:

The majority of the time seems to be spent inside `det`. (Check out [line_profiler](http://packages.python.org/line_profiler/) to find this out yourself.) You can try to speed that part up by linking Numpy with the Intel MKL, but other than that, there is not much that can be done.

You can speed up the other part of the code like this:

```
minor = np.zeros([nrows-1, ncols-1])
for row in xrange(nrows):
    for col in xrange(ncols):
        minor[:row,:col] = matrix[:row,:col]
        minor[row:,:col] = matrix[row+1:,:col]
        minor[:row,col:] = matrix[:row,col+1:]
        minor[row:,col:] = matrix[row+1:,col+1:]
        ...
```

This gains some 10-50% total runtime depending on the size of your matrices. The original code has Python `range` and list manipulations, which are slower than direct slice indexing. You could try also to be more clever and copy only parts of the minor that actually change --- however, already after the above change, close to 100% of the time is spent inside `numpy.linalg.det` so that furher optimization of the othe parts does not make so much sense.

Comment: Excellent answer!  My matrices are invertible so that one liner is a huge time saver.

Comment: This calculates the adjoint matrix, not the cofactor matrix.
det(A) * inverse(A) = adjoint(A)

Comment: @v3ga: please actually read the answer. It computes `det(A) * inverse(A)^T`. Cofactor is the transpose of the adjugate.

Answer (score 2):

The calculation of `np.array(range(row)+range(row+1,nrows))[:,np.newaxis]` does not depended on `col` so you could could move that outside the inner loop and cache the value.  Depending on the number of columns you have this might give a small optimization.

Answer (score 2):

```
from sympy import *
A = Matrix([[1,2,0],[0,3,0],[0,7,1]])
A.adjugate().T
```

And the output (which is cofactor matrix) is:

```
Matrix([
[ 3, 0,  0],
[-2, 1, -7],
[ 0, 0,  3]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the inverse and determinant, I'd suggest using the SVD

```
def cofactors(A):
    U,sigma,Vt = np.linalg.svd(A)
    N = len(sigma)
    g = np.tile(sigma,N)
    g[::(N+1)] = 1
    G = np.diag(-(-1)**N*np.product(np.reshape(g,(N,N)),1)) 
    return U @ G @ Vt
```

Comment: Could you please provide a reference for this algorithm? I am especially interested in what is happening with g and G. I have seen algorithms based on SVD, but they also used the determinants. Eg: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/33028/fast-algorithm-for-computing-cofactor-matrix

Comment: This derivation comes from applying a Single Value Decomposition to the general definition of the cofactor matrix. C = det(A) A^{-T} which is equal to det(U) det(S) det(V) U S^{-1} V^T. The det(U) and det(V) are just +1 or -1 as they're orthonormal matrices and G is the reduction of det(S) S^{-1} (Sometimes labelled as Gamma). This all comes together as det(U)det(V) U G V^{T} (as shown above)