# Fast algorithm for computing cofactor matrix

Tags: numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, scientific-computing

I wonder if there is a fast algorithm, say (O(n^3)) for computing the cofactor matrix (or conjugate matrix) of a N*N square matrix. And yes one could first compute its determinant and inverse separately and then multiply them together. But how about this square matrix is non-invertible?

I am curious about the accepted answer here:[Speed up python code for computing matrix cofactors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527641/speed-up-python-code-for-computing-matrix-cofactors)

What would it mean by "This probably means that also for non-invertible matrixes, there is some clever way to calculate the cofactor (i.e., not use the mathematical formula that you use above, but some other equivalent definition)."?

Comment: This question is off-topic on StackOverflow as it is not about programming (and probably will not attract enough attention). However, I would be happy to answer it on [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks! I opened it at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/33028/fast-algorithm-for-computing-cofactor-matrix

Answer (score 0):

Factorize M = L x D x U, where
`L` is lower triangular with ones on the main diagonal,
`U` is upper triangular on the main diagonal, and
`D` is diagonal.

You can use back-substitution as with Cholesky factorization, which is similar. Then,

M^{ -1 } = U^{ -1 } x D^{ -1 } x L^{ -1 }

and then transpose the cofactor matrix as :

Cof( M )^T = Det( U ) x Det( D ) x Det( L ) x M^{ -1 }.

If `M` is singular or nearly so, one element (or more) of `D` will be zero or nearly zero.  Replace those elements with zero in the matrix product and 1 in the determinant, and use the above equation for the transpose cofactor matrix.