# How to access list and matrix using if and how to use a defined function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am confused by the python code mentioned below. What does the statement `not i:2 if i==2 else None:2 if i==1 else 1` mean?
Besides, how can I use the function `cofactor(A, (i, j))`; can you give an example?

```
def cofactor(A, (i, j)):
    ’’’Cofactor[i,j] of 3x3 matrix A’’’
    a = A[not i:2 if i==2 else None:2 if i==1 else 1,
          not j:2 if j==2 else None:2 if j==1 else 1] 
    return (-1)**(i+j) * (a[0,0]*a[1,1] - a[1,0]*a[0,1])
```

Comment: That code is nonsense.  Where did you find it?

Comment: Use of proper indentation is required inside functions. The code is very difficult to understand otherwise.

Comment: I didn't edit the text well. Now it looks well now. @Tim Roberts

Comment: yeah. I edit the text again @Sanskar Singh

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the code is from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.1878.pdf (Apendix A).

First, the backticks in the code are actually `'`. I guess the paper prints backticks just because the journal (or the authors) didn't handle the character properly.

Now `not i:2 if i==2 else None:2 if i==1 else 1` is just a slicing like what `A[...:...:...]` would mean for example.

`x if a else y` is what's called [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions); it evaluates to `x` if `a` is true, and `y` otherwise.

So, for example, if `i == 1`, then

1. `not i` becomes `False`, since `1` is Truthy.
2. `2 if i == 2 else None` becomes `None`.
3. `2 if i == 1 else 1` becomes `2`.

So `not i:2 if i==2 else None:2 if i==1 else 1` in this case becomes `False:None:2`, which is `0::2` when used as a slice. Likewise, when `j == 1`, the second one `not j:2 if j==2 else None:2 if j==1 else 1` becomes `0::2`. Therefore `a = A[::2, ::2]` if `i == 1, j == 2`.

An example follows:

```py
import numpy as np

def cofactor(A, ij):
    '''Cofactor[i,j] of 3x3 matrix A'''
    i, j = ij
    a = A[not i:2 if i==2 else None:2 if i==1 else 1,
          not j:2 if j==2 else None:2 if j==1 else 1] 
    return (-1)**(i+j) * (a[0,0]*a[1,1] - a[1,0]*a[0,1])

A = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3) # an example matrix; [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
print(cofactor(A, (1, 2))) # 6
```

Note that I modified the function a little bit; apparently, defining a function with arguments `(A, (i, j))` as in the paper is not a valid syntax. So I added a line to explicitly unpack the tuple `ij` into `i` and `j`.

Comment: thanks for your explanation very much. Your explanation is clear and full of detials. But I am surprised that how can you know this part code comes from the neutrino related arxriv article.  Do you also study particle physics?  Glad to meet you here today. @j1-lee

Answer (score 0):

The complicated looking slices in fact just remove row `i` and column `j` from the matrix, prior to computing the cofactor from the remaining 2x2 matrix, similar to this [more general function for computing cofactors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527641/speed-up-python-code-for-computing-matrix-cofactors). The line could more readably be written as:

```
    a = np.delete(np.delete(A, i, axis=0), j, axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Your explanation realy helped me understand the code.