# How to get the minor of a matrix using numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to write a function that does the following: 
Given a square matrix    and an index   , find and return the sub-matrix that is the minor corresponding to element at index    of the first row of

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy Routine for Computing Matrix Minors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858213/numpy-routine-for-computing-matrix-minors)

Comment: You mean something like `A[1:, np.arange(A.shape[1]) != i]`?

Comment: You could also just do `np.delete(A[1:], i, 1)`